# Serialize in JSON a base64 encoded data

Tags: json, python-3.x, serialization, base64

I'm writing a script to automate data generation for a demo and I need to serialize in a JSON some data. Part of this data is an image, so I encoded it in base64, but when I try to run my script I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lazyAutomationScript.py", line 113, in <module>
    json.dump(out_dict, outfile)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 178, in dump
    for chunk in iterable:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/encoder.py", line 422, in _iterencode
    yield from _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/encoder.py", line 396, in _iterencode_dict
    yield from chunks
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/encoder.py", line 396, in _iterencode_dict
    yield from chunks
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/encoder.py", line 429, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/encoder.py", line 173, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
  TypeError: b'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAADWcAABRACAYAAABf7ZytAAAABGdB...
     ...
   BF2jhLaJNmRwAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC' is not JSON serializable
```

As far as I know, a base64-encoded-whatever (a PNG image, in this case) is just a string, so it should pose to problem to serializating. What am I missing?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

You must be careful about the datatypes.

If you read a binary image, you get bytes.
If you encode these bytes in base64, you get ... bytes again! (see documentation on [b64encode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b64encode))

json can't handle raw bytes, that's why you get the error.

I have just written some example, with comments, I hope it helps:

```
from base64 import b64encode
from json import dumps

ENCODING = 'utf-8'
IMAGE_NAME = 'spam.jpg'
JSON_NAME = 'output.json'

# first: reading the binary stuff
# note the 'rb' flag
# result: bytes
with open(IMAGE_NAME, 'rb') as open_file:
    byte_content = open_file.read()

# second: base64 encode read data
# result: bytes (again)
base64_bytes = b64encode(byte_content)

# third: decode these bytes to text
# result: string (in utf-8)
base64_string = base64_bytes.decode(ENCODING)

# optional: doing stuff with the data
# result here: some dict
raw_data = {IMAGE_NAME: base64_string}

# now: encoding the data to json
# result: string
json_data = dumps(raw_data, indent=2)

# finally: writing the json string to disk
# note the 'w' flag, no 'b' needed as we deal with text here
with open(JSON_NAME, 'w') as another_open_file:
    another_open_file.write(json_data)
```

Comment: I had a similar problem when I was using Gmail API to send Email with this specific action `return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string())}`. @spky Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I am doing the same for excel file, everything is happening correctly but file written to disk is corrupted, could not be opened normally

Comment: Thank you so much. This was incredibly confusing to me and this explains it really well.

Comment: @spky In the above we are sending the string image. How to again convert back that string to image

Comment: @spky any idea, how to read the image back using OpenCV from this json_data.

Answer (score 13):

Alternative solution would be encoding stuff on the fly with a custom encoder:

```
import json
from base64 import b64encode

class Base64Encoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    # pylint: disable=method-hidden
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, bytes):
            return b64encode(o).decode()
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
```

Having that defined you can do:

```
m = {'key': b'\x9c\x13\xff\x00'}
json.dumps(m, cls=Base64Encoder)
```

It will produce:

```
'{"key": "nBP/AA=="}'
```

Answer (score 12):

> What am I missing?

The error is yelling that a `binary` is not JSON serializable.

```py
from base64 import b64encode

# *binary representation* of the base64 string
assert b64encode(b"binary content")                 == b'YmluYXJ5IGNvbnRlbnQ='

# base64 string
assert b64encode(b"binary content").decode('utf-8') ==  'YmluYXJ5IGNvbnRlbnQ='
```

The latter is definitely "JSON serializable" because is the base64 string representation of the binary `b"binary content"`.

Comment: `TypeError: b'...' is not JSON serializable` means that "a binary is not JSON serializable"