# How to solve 'Bad request error' for creating new Cloudant doc with attachement .

Tags: python, json, cloudant

I'm working on python client examples  with Cloudant NoSQLDB. For relatively simple document creation, it's OK.   However, trying to upload a base64 encoded file as an attachment to doc, I run into a problem that I cannot solve by myself.
Please help me.

Here is my code.

```
from cloudant.client import Cloudant
from cloudant.error import CloudantException
from cloudant.result import Result,ResultByKey
import base64
.
.
.

client.connect()
databaseName = "mydata1"
myDatabase = client[databaseName]

targetfile = "chibitest.png"
with open(targetfile,"rb") as fp:
    byte_content = fp.read()
dataContentb= base64.b64encode(byte_content)
dataContent = dataContentb.decode()

jsonDoc = {
    "nameField": "sample1",
    "_attachements":{
      targetfile: 
      {"content-type":"image/png",
       "data":dataContent}
     }
}
newDocument = myDatabase.create_document(jsonDoc)
```

The result Error is as follows:

```
raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request doc_validation Bad
special document member: _attachements for url:https://.....cloudant.com/mydata1
```

(without  "_attachements" section , it works appropriately.)

Additional information.

In the above code, the line;

```
dataContent = dataContentb.decode()
```

is the one I needed  to solve json error.  This is thanks to an article,  [Serialize in JSON a base64 encoded data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37225035/serialize-in-json-a-base64-encoded-data)

Although, I could not specify  "ENCODING" as decode() parameter as is shown in this article (because causing "not defined error"), I guess the resultant 
 dataContent would be  OK as far as I can see by inserting print statement..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right lines, but there is a [put_attachment](http://python-cloudant.readthedocs.io/en/latest/document.html#cloudant.document.Document.put_attachment) method dedicated to uploading attachments to an existing document.

Here's some working code

```
from cloudant.client import Cloudant
import base64

# connect
client = Cloudant('USER', 'PASS', account='ACCOUNT', connect=True)
session = client.session()

# create database
my_database = client.create_database('so46442945')

# load attachment
targetfile = "dog.png"
with open(targetfile,"rb") as fp:
    byte_content = fp.read()
dataContentb= base64.b64encode(byte_content)
dataContent = dataContentb.decode()

# Create a document using the Database API
jsonDoc = {
  '_id': 'mydoc', 
  'name': 'Julia',
  'age': 30,
  'pets': ['cat', 'dog', 'frog']
}
my_document = my_database.create_document(jsonDoc)

# Add attachment
my_document.put_attachment('dog.png', 'image/png', dataContent)

# disconnect
client.disconnect()
```

This creates a database, adds a document and then uploads an image attachment. After the script has finished, the document looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": "mydoc",
  "_rev": "2-0649fa69ed362501f97a328e4e81ee21",
  "age": 30,
  "name": "Julia",
  "pets": [
    "cat",
    "dog",
    "frog"
  ],
  "_attachments": {
    "dog.png": {
      "content_type": "image/png",
      "revpos": 2,
      "digest": "md5-l5CNi8JJBiQjUd+cS1ZFng==",
      "length": 436572,
      "stub": true
    }
  }
}
```